# KVC in UITableView subclass causing crash with accessibility enabled

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, accessibility, key-value-coding

I have a custom `UITableView` subclass in which I override `+accessInstanceVariablesDirectly` to return `NO` in order to ensure attributes with no setter cannot be set using KVC.

When removing this table view from the view hierarchy, the app crashes - sometimes - and now for the weird part: only if Accessibility is enabled! (i.e. the Accessibility Inspector is visible, or you have Accessibility enabled on a physical device)

If I do not override `+accessInstanceVariablesDirectly`, everything works fine. I figured maybe `UITableView` relies on accessing some instance variables directly - but then what is the point of this method, if I can break superclasses by using it? Is there a way to specify this behavior per-attribute, like `+automaticallyNotifiesObserversForKey:`? However I am baffled by the fact that this issue only exists when Accessibility is enabled.

I tried analyzing the project with various Instruments, but without success.

You can find a minimal project reproducing the issue [here](https://github.com/jenox/stackoverflow/tree/master/EXC_BAD_ACCESS). I would greatly appreciate any pointers on why this is happening or how to achieve what I want nonetheless.

Comment: About this line of your code `[self performSelector:@selector(debug) withObject:nil afterDelay:0.1];`. Can you do a `[self performSelectorOnMainThread:withObject:waitUntilDone` instead? I am not on my MAC and I wonder if its because the view is set on possibly a background thread

Comment: `-performSelector:` performs its selector on the same thread it has been called. Also this is just an 'optimization' to reproduce the bug, in my real application the views are replaced as a response to a user action which obviously happens on the main thread,

Comment: I run the demo you give in simulator(ios 8.3 iphone5s), it works well, no crash!

Comment: Please be sure to file a radar

Comment: @ZyZhao you have to enable the accessibility inspector.

Comment: I guess you might have seen it, but when zombies are enabled, the following error is logged: `[TableView release]: message sent to deallocated instance `.

Comment: @user3584460 So where is the error and how can I fix it?

Comment: It seems that the accessibility inspector keeps reference to the first `tableView` that is created, although it is deallocated. I do not know why this happens - it might as well be a bug with the accessibility inspector. Something else - why do you want to create different instances of `tableView` instead of just creating it once and reusing it? If you reuse the `tableView` you won't get that error.

Comment: @user3584460 I can't reuse it in my application. This is just a sample project reproducing the error.

Comment: OK, if the delegate is moved in a separate class, then there is no crash. I tried setting breakpoint for all exceptions and it always stops on the line where the delegate is set (regardless of whether it is `self` or a separate class.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This issue appears to be fixed in iOS 9.